# no module named 'social' when I'm trying to get a new facebook access_token in the postman using my new heroku domain name instead of localhost:8000

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, facebook-access-token, python-social-auth

There Are The Steps I Followed To get an access_token after pushed my project into heroku

---

1. I Changed My Site Url Of My App On Facebook from localhost:8000 to https://whispering-hamlet-67095.herokuapp.com/
2. changed my ALLOWED_HOSTS In Settings.py To ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost","whispering-hamlet-67095.herokuapp.com"]
3. This Step=> ###  Testing On PostMan To Get facebook access_token As Usual Like I Used To Do When My Project is Only Running Locally But I Got This error When I Changed The Url From localhost:8000/ to https://whispering-hamlet-67095.herokuapp.com/ [image]

---

- So What Should I Do To Use Facebook access_token with my new heroku domain and solve this error

---

And There Are My settings.py code :

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


----------



SECRET_KEY = 'lr2g%2&4666(ghg%&dqhlzcm=f9$5&%q6l*z1+v7vh+khxackr'


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost","whispering-hamlet-67095.herokuapp.com"]


----------


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'egystoreapp',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2',
    'social_django',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'bootstrap3',
]


----------


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


----------


ROOT_URLCONF = 'egystores.urls'


----------


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]


----------


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'egystores.wsgi.application'


----------


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


----------


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


----------


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


----------


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')


----------


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL = '/restaurant/login/'


----------


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


----------


import dj_database_url
db_form_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_form_env)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

]


----------


SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '456241455340421'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '7742368b0f0fc189622fb625c6871a65'


SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id, name, email'
}
----------
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'egystoreapp.social_auth_pipeline.create_user_by_type',  # <--- set the path to the function
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
----------
SITE_ID = 1
```

- And In urls.py :

---

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from egystoreapp import views, apis

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),

    #Restaurant
    url(r'^restaurant/sign-in/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='restaurant/sign_in.html'),
        name = 'restaurant-sign-in'),
    url(r'^restaurant/sign-out', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'),
        name = 'restaurant-sign-out'),
    url(r'^restaurant/sign-up', views.restaurant_sign_up,
        name = 'restaurant-sign-up'),
    url(r'^restaurant/$', views.restaurant_home, name = 'restaurant-home'),

    url(r'^restaurant/account/$',views.restaurant_account, name = 'restaurant-account'),
    url(r'^restaurant/meal/$',views.restaurant_meal, name = 'restaurant-meal'),
    url(r'^restaurant/meal/add/$',views.restaurant_add_meal, name = 'restaurant-add-meal'),
    url(r'^restaurant/meal/edit/(?P<meal_id>\d+)/$',views.restaurant_edit_meal, name = 'restaurant-edit-meal'),
    url(r'^restaurant/order/$',views.restaurant_order, name = 'restaurant-order'),
    url(r'^restaurant/report/$',views.restaurant_report, name = 'restaurant-report'),

    url(r'^api/social/', include('rest_framework_social_oauth2.urls')),


    # /convert-token used for (sign-in/ sign-up)
    # /revoke-token (sign out)
    url(r'^api/restaurant/order/notification/(?P<last_request_time>.+)/$', apis.restaurant_order_notification),



    # APIs for Customers
    url(r'^api/customer/restaurants/$', apis.customer_get_restaurants),
    url(r'^api/customer/meals/(?P<restaurant_id>\d+)/$', apis.customer_get_meals),
    url(r'^api/customer/order/add/$', apis.customer_add_order),
    url(r'^api/customer/order/latest/$', apis.customer_get_latest_order),

    # APIs for Drivers
    url(r'^api/driver/order/ready/$' ,apis.driver_get_ready_orders),
    url(r'^api/driver/order/pick/$' ,apis.driver_pick_order),
    url(r'^api/driver/order/latest/$' ,apis.driver_get_latest_order),
    url(r'^api/driver/order/complete/$' ,apis.driver_complete_order),
    url(r'^api/driver/revenue/$' ,apis.driver_get_revenue),


] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: @wp78de no, I didn't see any errors in this access_token the debug link gives me it's valid

Comment: I can't create a new token using my heroku app because it says no module named social but I can create a token locally

Comment: @wp78de ofcaurse this is the same way I used for localhost:8000 and it's worked but for  my new heroku domain name it gave me that error you can try it may be that will help